# Which one is more natural between the two?

Tags: word-usage

The #1 is an example sentence of the word "inadvertent".
But I feel like it doesn't make sense. Is it a correct sentence?

And which one is more natural below?

> 1. She made an inadvertent error ***when*** she knocked over the nail polish.
> 2. She made an inadvertent error ***that*** she knocked over the nail polish.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When" is more natural.

The error isn't knocking over the nail polish, that is the *consequence*. The mistake is "not looking at where she was waving her hands". At the time she made that mistake there was an immediate result, and so we use "when".

The word "inadvertent" is redundant here, as all errors are "inadvertent". The word may be used to emphasise that it was an accident, or it could be omitted.